# How to avoid switching "modes" of 4-way controller on Pentax K-5?

Tags: pentax, focus-point-selection, camera-controls

I quite enjoy ergonomics and user interface of Pentax K-5, except this one thing that drives me nuts.

I shoot almost exclusively using a selected focus point, and the arrow buttons have two "modes" - choosing the focus point, or providing "quick access" to settings such as white balance, drive mode, flash mode, color presets. My problem is that when picking up the camera, the controller is sometimes in the "settings" mode and instead of selecting a focus point I change a setting. So I might need to change the setting back, and switching the mode requires pressing OK button for about a second - all in all long enough to miss some good opportunities.

In this regard, I really like my older cheaper bodies with separate Fn button for switching the mode - switch the mode *only for subsequent click*. I've tried to remember keeping the controller in select mode, but then there will be times when action is going, and after doing the mode-switching dance once to get my WB right I shoot and forget to switch back. And from [what I read](http://www.pentaxforums.com/forums/pentax-k-5/189501-focus-spot-selection-k5.html#post1992120), the K-7 reverts to AF point selection mode after being turned off.

So, is there a way to avoid switching by accessing at least WB and drive modes through some other means, or to define a button function like Fn of a cheaper body (e.g. I could give up AEL easily)? Or at least if I could make it forget the "mode" it had before switching off. I don't remember seeing anything relevant in the manual, and seem to have it misplaced it somewhere :(

Comment: Indeed the K-5 ergonomics are excellent but the K20D and K10D did better in a few aspects and the *Fn* button is one of those.

Comment: On the plus side, a quick press on the Okay button now (as in the K20D/K10D) returns the focus point to the center. I missed that on my K-7.

Comment: Anyway, this annoys me too. Something to write to Pentax about; theoretically a firmware update could add this to the existing menu for which items to remember or reset at power off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manual pretty much says no, the OK button on the rear controls this toggle. It does say, though, that when in the mode to adjust focus there's a little rectangular controller icon that appears in the viewfinder. I checked that on my K-5 and the icon will appear down and immediately to the left of the shutter speed value. So not ideal but at least there's a visual indicator when shooting if you can get used to looking for that before adjusting.

Anyways. that's what I found, but the manual is online at the [Pentax site](http://www.pentax.jp/english/support/man-pdf/k-5.pdf) if you want to dig around some more.